# Using multiple pragma on same for-loop for auto-vectorization on GCC and ICC

Tags: c++, gcc, simd, icc, auto-vectorization

When there is a simple loop running on simple arrays,

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
       a[i]=b[i]+c[i];
}
```

GCC and ICC behave differently with pragmas. So I experimented with pragmas and observed that ICC benefits from this:

```
#pragma vector always vectorlength(16)
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
       a[i]=b[i]+c[i];
}
```

and GCC benefits from this:

```
#pragma gcc ivdep
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
       a[i]=b[i]+c[i];
}
```

What is the right approach to support both compilers? Something like this:

```
#pragma vector always vectorlength(16)
#pragma gcc ivdep
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
       a[i]=b[i]+c[i];
}
```

or using define macros? (I'm not fond of macros but can use if no other option is left)

I'm trying to support `#pragma omp simd safelen(16)` for platforms that do not have OpenMP. Closest pragmas I found are gcc ivdep and vector always but still they are not as fast as omp's pragma. Probably I'm missing some more pragmas.

- a,b and c are simple arrays in same stack and they are aligned to 64.
- the function has `__attribute__((always_inline))` which helps ICC for 4x performance (but still slower than GCC by 50%)
- ICC flags: `-std=c++14  -xCORE-AVX512  -qopt-zmm-usage=high  -O3  -lgomp -fmath-errno -mprefer-vector-width=512  -ftree-vectorize -lpthread`
- GCC flags: `-std=c++14 -march=cascadelake -fmath-errno  -mavx512f -O3 -lgomp -mprefer-vector-width=512  -ftree-vectorize -lpthread`

Lastly, why is there no `#pragma vector always` equivalent for GCC?

Comment: soo `#if __icc__ do this #elif __GNUC__ do this #endif`?

Comment: As a one-liner it looks good but I still need to know if using two pragmas ok or not.

Comment: You could just use ifdefs to `#define VECTOR_LOOP ...` appropriately, then use `pragma VECTOR_LOOP`, unless you ever actually want more than 1 pragma for a single compiler.  That's the normal solution for stuff like `__attribute__((always_inline))` vs. `__declspec(inline)` or whatever other compiler-specific decorations.

Comment: I was asking for different compiler support with 1 pragma. I'm using define macro then. Thanks.